# Is it okay not to get married due to being an ex-porn watcher?

Tags: nikah

I'm an ex-porn watcher, I've lost a lot of my dignity recently I have been told by people that do not know I watch this filth that porn permanently ruins your marriage and you can't fix it even if you repent. I'm willing to accept the truth and my parents give me so much freedom so they won't force me to marry.

I'm planning to adopt so I will be able to have kids. I've stopped watching porn for three months. I'm making this decision for the sake of my benefit.

Comment: This is not related to porn, but isn't it easier to adopt if you are married ? Isn't it also better for the children ?